# How to align text similar to tabular while using align environment

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, align, alignment

In LaTeX, I would like to align some text so that looks something like this:

```
"⇒": some text 
      [an equation in align* environment]
      more text

"⇐": some other text
      [another equation]
      even more text
```

without the use of minipages, and without me having to manually specify any width or similar every time I want to insert something like this. I would also like, that the "more text" place holder is aligned with the "even more text" place holder, if for example I write something longer than `"⇐"`.

So basically just like inside a tabular environment with invisible borders, but tabular won't let me use `align*`

Comment: you can use align in a p column of a tabular but you probably want `$\begin{aligned}...` in an l column

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I can't get it running in `p`-columns either. What's the difference to using `l`? It seems that I always have to specify a width with `p`-cells which is something I want to avoid.

Comment: `l` is like `mbox` so horizontal mode (LR-mode in latex book) so can not have display constructs like align, or paragraphs or `\vspace` . `p` is like `\parbox` (par-mode in latex book) so can have all those things.   You want `l` column and `aligned` here not `align`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks a lot, I was really blind. Using aligned in an l column worked perfectly now, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`align` is a full width display. `aligned` is essentially the same alignment but makes a box the natural width of the alignment, which can be inlined in other constructs.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \Rightarrow:&\text{some text}\\
     &\begin{aligned}
       1&=3-2\\
       10&=3^2+1^2\\
       \end{aligned}\\
     &\text{more text}\\[10pt]
\Leftarrow:& \text{some other text}\\
     &\begin{aligned}
       2&=1+1\\
       5^2&=3^2+4^2\\
       \end{aligned}\\
      &\text{even more text}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm using the aligned within a tabular environment `l` cell now, as you suggested before for better spacing, but I guess this works as well. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Another option to the one mentioned by David Carlisle would be to use something like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  asdf & text \\
       &
  $ \begin{aligned}
      a +  b & = c    \\
      c      & = b+ a
    \end{aligned} $
\end{tabular}
```